# why is codemirror turning up readonly under vue

Tags: vue.js, codemirror

If I have the following code, code mirror comes up readonly

```html
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2">
        <textarea id="code"><h1>hi</h1></textarea>
      </div>   
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
      var vue  = new Vue( 
      {
        el : ".container",
        created() {this.editor = CodeMirror.fromTextArea(document.getElementById('code'), {lineNumbers: true, mode:"htmlmixed"});}
      })
  </script>
```

if I change "container" to "container1" so that the vue element doesn't match - it's editable.

How do I fix it?

Comment: The created() hook does mount the DOM yet. So you can't that element yet.

Comment: changed it to mounted - and it wokred perfectly - thanks!    Seems strange though that it _seemed_ to work - just wasn't editable.   Oh well - add it as an answer so I can accept it.